# Using MultiValued Map with Glassfish jersey jar

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs, jersey-client

We've upgraded to Glass fish Jersey from Sun Jersey. We've following piece of code which is not working with glassfish jar and earlier was working with sun jar.

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> args = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    args.add("local", sharedDrivePath);
    args.add("nas", nasPath);
    args.add("controlNo", controlNumber);
    ImageBean eReportImageBean = new ImageBean();
    response = resource.path("getImage").queryParam(args).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .get(ClientResponse.class);
    ImageBean = response.readEntity(ImageBean.class);
```

Here MultivaluedMapImpl is not available with glassfish jersey and also queryparam(string, string) is not supported with Webtarget resource.

Please help with a feasilble solution on this.

```
ImageBean ImageBean = new EReportImageBean();
    response = resource.path("getImage").queryParam("local",sharedPath).queryParam("as",asPath).queryParam("No", Number).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);
    ImageBean = response.readEntity(ImageBean.class);
```

Now I'm getting below exception:

javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/xml, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.

Please help

Comment: You cant put all the query params in a map in this version. You have to set them individually. See [the docs on the Client](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4369) for more info on using the new client

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've gone through document but it is showing example for for single query param, I have 3 parameters to add

Comment: You can call queryParam() more than once

Comment: Thanks! I think I understood what to you're trying to say, I'll try to do the same

Comment: [5.3.5. Invoking a HTTP request](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4719)